# I try to deploy opencell to wildfly. When I paste my opencell.war to standalone directory wildfly throws error

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-10

{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"opencell.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"opencell.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"opencell.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/meveo/event/monitoring/ClusterEventMonitor (Module \"deployment.opencell.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): javax/jms/MessageListener"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"opencell.war\".POST_MODULE"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}

Comment: There is no question here. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find the org/meveo/event/monitoring/ClusterEventMonitor class by the server .

Comment: But I have followed the documentation given by opencell.